# MVVM Light making an HTTP Get request using Webapi

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, asp.net-web-api

I am a newbie when it comes to MVVM and Web related technologies.  We are currently developing an MVVM client app using the latest MVVMLight framework in Visual Studios 2013.  The application uses Microsoft's Webapi (latest version) to get data into our model via HTTP requests.  Our code executes up to the point where the HTTP request is made, and we have confirmed that the server is getting the request, gathering up the requested data and returning it as JSON.  However the client never sees the response, it just continues to wait for the response.  Its almost as though we are seeing an issue that seems to do with threads.  Where the request was made on one thread, but the response is being received on another.  Here is our code (where the HTTP request is made):

public class DataService : IDataService
{

```
    #region Fields

    private HttpClient _client;
    private LfActivityDataReturnObject _activityReturnObj;
    private AdroServices _adroServices;
    private bool _selectedProcssingOptionPosted = false;
    private bool _activityDataSuccessfullyRetrieved = false;
    private decimal _incomingLFEntryId;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public DataService()
    {
        try
        {    
            //Get command line arguments
            string[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

            for (int i = 1; i < arguments.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            if (!Decimal.TryParse(arguments[i], out _incomingLFEntryId))
                            {
                                _incomingLFEntryId = -1;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }

            if (_incomingLFEntryId <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Invalid Activity Shortcut Entry ID: {0}", _incomingLFEntryId));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {                
            throw e;
        }
    }

    #endregion



    #region Methods



    public void GetGeneralInformationModel(Action<GeneralInformationModel, Exception> callback)
    {
        Exception locException = null;
        GeneralInformationModel locGeneralInformationModel = null;

        if (_adroServices == null)
        {
            try
            {
                //Start the HTTP request
                GetActivityDataAsync().Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                locException = e;
            }
            // change? should be for http success but adro failure
            if (_activityDataSuccessfullyRetrieved)
            {
                _adroServices = new AdroServices(_activityReturnObj);
                locGeneralInformationModel = new GeneralInformationModel(_adroServices);
            }
            else
            {
                Exception e2 = new Exception("Error retrieving activity data in DataService");
                locException = e2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            locGeneralInformationModel = new GeneralInformationModel(_adroServices);
        }

        var item = locGeneralInformationModel;
        callback(item, locException);          
    }   

    //Get data from the repository via the service layer.
    private async Task GetActivityDataAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            using (this._client = new HttpClient())
            {
                _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:52512//");
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                //Line below is where the app just runs getting no response
                HttpResponseMessage caseDataResponse = await _client.GetAsync(string.Format("api/LfUrs/{0}", _incomingLFEntryId));

                if (caseDataResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    _activityReturnObj = await caseDataResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<LfActivityDataReturnObject>();

                    if (_activityReturnObj.ReturnCode == 0)
                    {                            
                        _activityDataSuccessfullyRetrieved = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _activityDataSuccessfullyRetrieved = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _activityDataSuccessfullyRetrieved = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _activityDataSuccessfullyRetrieved = false;
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

We have tried using Fiddler to get more information but Fiddler doesn't seem to be able to reveal any of the details.  Also I should mention that we are simulating the server on the local host and as I stated above, we have confirmed the server gets the request and returns the data.  My associates and I are starting to think this has something to do with the MVVM Light Framework and the IOC or possibly threading.  When we use this same code in a MVVM solution that doesn't use the framework it works.  Any help would be sincerely appreciated.  Thanks...Mike

Comment: Also the local host is using IIS Express to receive the HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.  Somehow, in my app.xaml, the Dispatcher.Helper had been moved to the event On_Startup rather than being contained in the class constructor.  Additionally I had to move the HTTP stuff into the ADRO services class and make sure it was constructed in the App constructor in app.xaml right after Dispatcher.Helper.  But thanks to everyone who participates here on StackOverFlow.  This resource is an absolute life-saver.  Thanks